# How do I return a status code error from a REST Service while using an OnError handler?

Tags: rest, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, application.cfc

I'm trying to set up some REST Web Services with ColdFusion 10, and if I have an onError handler in place in the Application.cfc the error status code is not returned back to to the Consumer.

Let's consider this Application.cfc

```
<cfcomponent displayname="ApplicationCFC" output="true" >
    <cfscript>
        this.name = "learnWith";
        this.applicationTimeout = createTimeSpan(1,1,0,0);
        this.sessionManagement = "false";
        this.restsettings.autoregister = true;
        this.restsettings.skipCFCWithError = true;
    </cfscript>

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart" returntype="boolean" output="true">
        <cfset RestInitApplication(expandPath('/myDir'),"lw")>
        <cfreturn true>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Now consider the service, like this:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/user">
    <cffunction name="authenticate" access="remote" restpath="/login" returntype="String" httpmethod="POST"
            consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
        <cfset requestData = getHTTPRequestData()>
        <cfset userInfo = deserializeJSON(ToString(requestData.content)) />

        <!--- cfquery to load user data ---->

        <cfif local.dataQuery.recordcount EQ 1>
            <cfset local.userVO = createObject()> <!--- create and populate userVo here --->
            <cfreturn SerializeJSON(local.userVO)>
        <cfelse>
            <!--- user not found, throw 401 error --->
            <cfthrow type="RestError" errorcode="401"  />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

This code works perfectly from Postman.  If I pass in the proper credentials

```
{
    "userName": "user",
    "password": "hashedPassword
}
```

I get a user object back as expected with a 200 response.

[image: Correct Credentials Login]

If I pass in fake or invalid credentials:

```
{
    "userName": "fakeuser",
    "password": "fakePassword
}
```

I get a 401 error back:

[image: Failed Authentication]

That's perfect.  However, I want to use a global error handler for the CFC, both for non-REST Service based code and to log possible REST Service errors.  If I add this into the Application.cfc

```
    <cffunction name="onError" returnType="void" output="true">
        <cfargument name="exception" required="true">
        <cfargument name="eventname" type="string" required="true">
        <!--- error logging here --->
        <cfthrow type="RestError" errorcode="401" />
        <!--- or 
            <cfthrow type="#arguments.exception.Cause.Cause.type#" 
                     errorcode="#arguments.exception.Cause.Cause.code#">--->

    </cffunction>
```

ColdFusion returns a 500 Internal Server error message.

[image: 500 Internal Server Error]

I experimented with cfheader both in the CFC method and within the onError handler:

```
<cfheader statusCode = "401" statusText = "RestError">
```

It'll return a 200 with no body instead of a 401 status:

[image: 200 error]

I've tried various iterations of this, but am at a loss.  Can I use status codes from a ColdFusion rest service while also having an onError handler in place?  And if so, how?

Comment: I think the problem may be that you have this code in your `onError` method `<cfthrow type="RestError" errorcode="401" />`. An error has already happened for the `onError` method to be invoked and you are throwing another error from the error handler. I think you should be able to use `<cfheader statuscode="401" statustext="Unauthorized" />` within the `onError` method to return specific HTTP status codes. But don't use the `cfthrow`. At least not within the `onError` method itself.

Comment: @Miguel-F If I remove the cfthrow and have an onError method with no code, I still do not get the 401 back at the server.  The solution appears to be using the `restSetResponse()` to send back a response without using cfthrow or returning an item.  I'll post up something more in depth.

Comment: The answer you posted is a better solution than throwing an error but, to be clear, I didn't mean for you to try an onError method with no code. You still need to have the `<cfheader ...>` code that I mentioned.  Anyway, glad you got it working.

Comment: @Miguel-F The cfheader has no affect when using CF's REST APIs no matter if it is in the onError method or the CFC method.  I pointed this out in my original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do what I want.  Instead of using cfthrow to create an error I can create the response I needed with [restSetResponse](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/restsetresponse.html).

Inside the cffunction, first make sure to set the return type to void.

Then instead of returning an object or using cfthrow, you want to create a response object manually and send it back using `restSetResponse`.

This solved my issue:

```
<cfcomponent rest="true" restpath="/user">
    <cffunction name="authenticate" access="remote" restpath="/login" returntype="void" httpmethod="POST"
            consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
        <cfset requestData = getHTTPRequestData()>
        <cfset userInfo = deserializeJSON(ToString(requestData.content)) />

        <!--- cfquery to load user data ---->

        <cfset local.result = structNew()/>

        <cfif local.dataQuery.recordcount EQ 1>
            <cfset local.userVO = createObject()> <!--- create and populate userVo here --->

            <cfset local.result.status = 200 />
            <cfset local.result.content = SerializeJSON(local.userVO) />
        <cfelse>
            <cfset local.result.status = 401 />
            <cfset local.result.content = SerializeJSON({message: 'User Not Authorized'}) />
        </cfif>

        <cfset restSetResponse(local.result) />
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Once I did that I was able to control the response back to my consumer without triggering the `onError` method in the `Application.cfc`.